# How can I split my array to small arrays with 10 elements and shift 2 elements each time?

Tags: python, arrays, split, average

I am trying to split my array that is composed by 100 elements to small arrays each one has 10 elements and calculate their average (the average of each small array). My problem is that each time I want to shift two elements, is what I am doing in the next code is correct ?

```
Avg_Arr=[sum(Signal[k:k+10])/10 for k in range(0,N,2)]
```

More precisely, if my Array is the following

```
Array=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 .....]
```

My first small array is

```
My_Array1=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

==> average is (0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)/10

while my second one must be

```
My_Array2=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]
```

Comment: We don't know what `N` is but I'll assume it's the size of your big array. Why not `for k in range(0, N - 10, 2)`?

Comment: yes it is why do I need to add -10?

Comment: Towards the end of the `range`, (assume N=100) you'll get k=..., 94, 96, 98. Now make a guess at what `sum(Signal[k:k+10])/10` will compute to. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works:

```
Signal=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
N = len(Signal)
Avg_Arr=[sum(Signal[k:k+10])/10 for k in range(0, N-10, 2)]
print(Avg_Arr)
```

Beware that you must stop 10 elements from the end. Otherwise you are not averaging over 10 elements.